# Add new row for first of same group

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5, firebird-psql

I'm new to Firebird and need your help. I know that Firebird's task isn't to do a nice print.

I have a stored procedure with following reduced output:

| Drink | Name |
| --- | --- |
| Cola | Marcus |
| Cola | Siegfried |
| Fanta | Jochen |
| Beer | Anna |
| Beer | Manuel |

I want to add a new row and column before the first value of each group of Drink with the name of the Drink in it.

So the output should be:

| Drink | Drinks for print | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cola | Cola |  |
| Cola |  | Marcus |
| Cola |  | Siegfried |
| Fanta | Fanta |  |
| Fanta |  | Jochen |
| Beer | Beer |  |
| Beer |  | Anna |
| Beer |  | Manuel |

I am using Firebird 2.5.8

Comment: Do you want to modify the procedure to do this, or do you want to keep the procedure as-is and add this on execution?

Comment: I want to keep the procedure as-is and add this on execution.

Comment: This, however, does not require imperative programmers as SPs or execute-blocks. It can be done as a usual SQL query. Using Window Functions of FB3 is most idiomatic way, but using FB2 it still is possible combining CTEs and UNIONs :-D Granted, such a query better be run over source data, nor over existing SP's output, or at least after caching full SP output to some GTT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to modify the existing stored procedure, but instead want to 'decorate' the output of the stored procedure, you would need to do something like this:

```sql
execute block
  returns (
    drink varchar(50), 
    "Drink for print" varchar(50), 
    name varchar(50))
as
  declare drink_intermediate varchar(50);
  declare name_intermediate varchar(50);
begin
  for select drink, name 
    from drinks 
    order by drink 
    into drink_intermediate, name_intermediate
  do
  begin
    if (drink is distinct from drink_intermediate) then
    begin
        drink = drink_intermediate;
        "Drink for print" = drink_intermediate;
        name = null;
        suspend;
        "Drink for print" = null;
    end
    name = name_intermediate;
    suspend;
  end
end
```

That is, each time the drink changes, you need to add an extra row.

You can also do something like this in DSQL, but this probably more expensive when you have a lot of rows due to the `distinct`:

```sql
select distinct 
  drink, 
  case a.type when 1 then drink end as "Drink for print", 
  case a.type when 2 then name end as name
from drinks
cross join (
  select 1 as type from RDB$DATABASE
  union all
  select 2 as type from RDB$DATABASE
) a
order by drink, type
```

That is, for each row of the stored procedure, we add an extra row with the `"Drinks for print"` column populated and the `name` not populated, and then we take a distinct (to remove the repeated rows), and sort for a consistent output.